# Is this function not recognizing my key when removing ads through in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, swift, ads, storekit

The ad works fine. However, when I add the if else statement to figure out if the user paid to remove ads, the ad doesn't pop up even if they haven't paid to have ads removed. The only print statement I get is "it called something" so I feel like there is something wrong with the key "Purchased". I checked to make sure they matched. Did I do something wrong with the key?

```
func showAd() {

    if let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Purchased") as? Bool{
        if purchased == true{
            interstitial = nil
            print("there is no ad!!!!")
        }else{
            self.interstitial = createInterstitialAd()
            print("there is an ad!!!")
        }
    } else {
        print("it called something")
    }

}
```

Edit: Here is the code where I set the key.

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions{
        if transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased{
            //User Payment Successfull
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Purchased")
            print("payment was successfull")
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeVC")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

        }else if transaction.transactionState == .failed{
            //User Payment failed
            print("transaction failed...")
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            if let error = transaction.error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps there is no value for that key, so `if purchased` never gets called.

Comment: I just updated my post and added a screen shot of the "Purchased" key that I set. The payments are working fine also.

Comment: You should put a breakpoint in your function `showAd` and see what's the value that you get from `UserDefaults`. Also, consider using the function `bool(forKey:) ` instead of `valueForKey` and then trying to cast it.

Comment: I set the breakpoint and it said the value for purchased = false @ShamasS

Comment: Do the same breakpoint for `paymentQueue` function, and if it goes through `.purchased`, then it means there's something wrong with the saving data. In that case, after saving `true`, call `UserDefaults.standards.syncrionize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Purchased") as? Bool
```

To:

```
if let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Purchased")
```

This makes it so `purchased` is not an optional. That way `if purchased` will always get called.

In fact, I would get rid of `if let` as it can't be nil:

```
let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Purchased")
```